# Without computing, is $\int_0^1 t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$ positive or negative? Give reasons for your answer.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

### Questions

Without computing, is $\int_0^1 t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$ positive or negative? Give reasons for your answer.

- Without computing, is $\int_0^2 t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$ larger or smaller than $\int_0^1 t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$? Give reasons for your answer.
- Without computing, is $\int_0^{2.25} t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$ larger or smaller than $\int_0^2 t(t-1)(t-2)\,dt$? Give reasons for your answer.

**Hint**: Graph the functions to answer.

### My Try

I tried to plot. Can anyone suggest on how to proceed?

[image]

Comment: It is good practice to make the body of the Question as self-contained as possible and not rely on the title to bear the burden of posing the problem.  Mathematical expressions can be posted with [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I've tried pretty much the same thing you did. The paper said I can't calculate the answer, and I have to graph the function, but I don't think I'm doing it right. Can you look at my answer in the link?

Answer (score 7):

Notice that for all $t \in (0,1)$,

$$ t>0, \;\;\; (t-1)<0 \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; (t-2)<0 $$

and it follows that

$$ t(t-1)(t-2)>0 $$

so that every element being integrated is positive. It follows that the integral is positive.

Comment: How do I graph the function and use the FToC to get the answer? Am I on track with what I wrote down on paper?

Comment: @jcw_mathstackexchange Your graph does not seem to be correct, since for $t=1$ we have that $t(t-1)(t-2) = 1(1-1)(1-2)=1\cdot 0 \cdot -1 = 0$. Calculate the function for $t=1/4,1/2,3/4$ and you should get a good idea of the plot.

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial function is continuous and hence can only change signs at roots. To see whether the function is positive on $(0,1)$ plug in some point in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to integrate on $\;[0,1]\;$ , we have $\;t>0\;$ . Now, take the other factor $\;(t-1)(t-2)\;$ . This is an upwards parabola which vanishes at $\;t =1,2\;$ and it is thus negative precise for $\;1\le t\le 2\;$ , so $\;t(t-1)(t-2)\;$ in $\;[0,1]\;$ is always non-negative and so is its integral. But since at $\;t=1/2\;$ the function is positive and it is a continuous function, the integral is actually positive.